# What kind of returned value from glibc functions needs to be free()d?

Tags: c++, c, glibc

As we know all dynamically allocated memories need to be freed using free() by the programmer himself. For the variables which the programmer himself creates and allocates memory to them almost there is not a problem as he knows what to call free() for. But what about pointers returned from glibc functions like getenv(). At first I thought I needed to free the memory pointed by the result of getenv() but then noticed the man says:

> As typically implemented, getenv() returns a pointer to a string
>   within the environment list.The caller must take care not to modify
>   this string, since that would change the environment of the process

This means the function getenv() hasn't called malloc() to create a new space for the string whose address is returning.
So which of the pointers returned from these functions explicitly needs to be freed?

Comment: Asking for _these functions_ comes out being a bit too broad. Usually it's documented if a returned pointer needs do be freed by the caller.

Comment: @haris Why none? You mean none of these functions call malloc() inside then return the address?

Comment: @hariz it's definitely not none - strdup is one example off the top of my head. The answer though is that you need to read the man page for every function to understand it.

Comment: As a very rough rule of thumb: If you expect the function to create a new object for you, you probably also have to get rid of dat somewhere. In general: read the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So which of the pointers returned from these functions explicitly needs to be freed?

The ones that the man page tells you to free, and *only* these.

Pointers returned by `getenv`, `fopen`, `strstr`, `memcpy` and many others should *not* be `free()`d (for obvious reasons: just read their man pages).